# Is it possible to have VS automatically create viewmodel, automapper mapping and fluent validator class when creating a new entity model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, auto-generate

A question from a lazy coder:

Whenever I create a new entity model, I almost always also want a corresponding viewmodel, an AutoMapper mapping and a FluentValidation validator class.

Is it possible to have Visual Studio do it for me at the stroke of a key combination?

For example, if I create the entity class `Person` in the file `Models/Person.cs`:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I could press a key combination, and let VS add the following automatically to my project:

**ViewModel, in a new file: `Models/PersonViewModel.cs`:**

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

**AutoMapper mapping, added in `Models/AutoMapperProfile.cs`:**

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>();
```

**FluentValidation validator, below the entity class in `Models/Person.cs`:**

```
// The class I wrote:
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

// The auto generated class:
public class PersonValidator : AbstractValidator<Person>
{
    public PersonValidator()
    {
        // Empty, no rules. Those I can add manually. ;)
    }    
}
```

**Transient for the validator, added in `Startup.cs`**

```
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Person>, PersonValidator>();
```

I have read a little about [Macros for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MacrosforVisualStudio), but from what I can tell, I don't think that could do the job.

Comment: Yes, but you'd have to write the code that auto-generates those things. Look around for "T4 templates"... I believe they are still a thing in VS2019...

Comment: Also, bear in mind that some developers/projects insist on a different view model for each view, not just one shared between views.  You should have a minimum of `CreateViewModel`, `EditViewModel`, `DeleteViewModel`, `IndexViewModel`

Comment: You need to try implement your own VS Extension based on your requirement, for VS Extension, you could refer [Create an extension with a VSPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-an-extension-with-a-vspackage?view=vs-2019)